# Intercepting signal between uC and LCD driver

Tags: pic, lcd

I'm trying to intercept the signals between an old Elan uC and a [HT-1622](http://www.hantronix.com/files/down/ht1622.pdf) LCD driver using a [PIC18F14K50](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41350E.pdf). There are 3 lines that are connected to the IOs of the uC: CS, WR(write clk) and DATA. At first sight it looks pretty simple, I just soldered 3 cables between the inputs on the HT-1622 and RB4, RB5 and RB6 on the PIC, and then I configured the registers like this:

```
TRISB = 1;   // set all pins on port b as inputs
ANSELH = 0; // digital inputs
WPUB = 0;  // disable the pull-up resistor
```

The problem arises when the PIC is powered on, the LCD driver stops working as it should, and the signals I get on the PIC inputs aren't valid (they're always 1). Once I disconnect VCC on the PIC, the LCD Driver works again. So it seems I'm missing something, any thoughts?

Comment: try using hex instead of decimal values for setting the bits, for example WPUB = 0x00

Comment: Yes, I ended using a binary value, but an hex value does the trick as well. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, there is another register that affects pull ups, [option_reg](http://www.pcbheaven.com/picpages/The_Option_Reg_Register/), take a look if you want if you will need it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TRISB = 1

This sets TRISB to 0x01: RB0 is input, all others are outputs.

Comment: Wow! You're absolutely right, what a dumb mistake. You saved my day. Thank you very much!

Comment: Enlightenment comes from having been there ...